# How do I get two photos into gimp?

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

How can I get two pictures into one gimp window?

Comment: did you tried copy paste??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Caleb Pendergast  -  Size the canvas larger than the combined dimensions of the two photos. Open each photo in GIMP, then copy and paste them into the new image as @Jack suggests.

You can adjust the images to your liking then crop the final image to the most appropriate size.

Answer (score 1):

Copy pasting should work just fine ;)